# SharePoint Designer Edit NewForm Link

Tags: web-part, list, sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part

I created a Data View Web Part based on an existing list in SharePoint Designer 2007, I included the SharePoint List Toolbar so users can create new items.  I want to use a custom List Form, in the New drop-down menu, for adding items to the list instead of the default NewForm.aspx, but in the code I only see the following:

```
<td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="">
                    <SharePoint:NewMenu runat="server"></SharePoint:NewMenu>
                </td>
```

I thought there might be a hyperlink embedded in the code somewhere that I could edit, but I couldn't see one.  Is there a straightforward way to edit the New List Item link to point to a custom List Form using SharePoint Designer?

Answer (score 2):

This might work out. Can you try setting your custom list form as the default form when a new item is created in the list.

1. In SPD, Go to the Lists folder and select the particulat list.
2. Right click on the list and click properties.
3. Go to "Supporting Files" tab.
4. Select "Item" as Content type specific forms
5. Click on Browse button for the new item form and select your custom form.

This should make the custom form as the default form throughout the list.

Comment: A little tip on this as SPD can be finicky about it, make sure the custom form is not open when you perform these steps or it doesn't seem to "stick" properly.

Comment: When I do this, it still refuses to update. Any ideas why?